# Php App Engine Strtotime Error

Tags: php, google-app-engine, strtotime

The following php line

```
$StartTime = strtotime("{$Event->EventDate} {$Event->StartTime}" );
```

Date is Y-m-d and time is H:i:s
works in Mamp but does not return a result in AppEngine.
Mamp is 5.6.10

Exact same file in both cases??

Comment: I found the answer. The time value was 3001-01-01 08:00:00 and it returned nothing in appengine but when I cut it to 2001-01-01 08:00:00 then it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.)